# Spring MVC 4 targetBeanName NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml, wro4j

I have a filter defined in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>wroFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/wro/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <display-name>DomainFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>DomainFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.cieloh.filter.DomainFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>DomainFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MySQL</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I have the bean defined in servlet-context.xml

```
<bean id="wroFilter" class="ro.isdc.wro.http.ConfigurableWroFilter">
    <property name="properties" ref="wroProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="wroProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:wro.properties" />
</bean>
```

I'm getting an org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wroFilter' is defined. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Is there a caused by or other details in the exception? The root cause maybe different than what you are seeing and is common in spring init errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are missing the spring listener and/or context-param configuration. Try adding the following configurations to web.xml:

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    <!-- classpath:app-context.xml -->
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can check out the following [example project](https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j-examples/tree/master/wro4j-spring) using spring with wro4j.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for the reply. I do have the listener in web.xml. I didn't include it originally. I edited my post to show the full web.xml.

Comment: Actually, I mirrored your web.xml, and things are working now. Thank you so much.